# Disable specific date and dates before specific date in react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to disable the dates before event date and event date. But not able to do .Please help to fix this out. Below I am sharing my code.

```
eventDate = newDate("2022-07-08");
const disableCustomDt = current => {
   return !eventDate .includes(current.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}
<DatePicker timeFormat={false} isValidDate={disableCustomDt} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

You can compare your current date with today and return true or false